# Strange behavior of gorm finder

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In a controller I have this finder

```
User.findByEmail('test@test.com')
```

And works.

Works even if I write

```
User.findByEmail(null)
```

But if i write

```
User.findByEmail(session.email)
```

and session.email is not defined (ergo is null) it throw exception

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: myapp.User.findByEmail() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Is this behavior right?

If i evaluate "session.email" it give me null so I think it must work as it do when I write 
User.findByEmail(null)

### Even more strange....

If I run this code in groovy console:

```
import myapp.User
User.findByEmail(null)
```

It return a user that has null email but if I run the same code a second time it return

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: myapp.User.findByEmail() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use standard `findBySomething` dynamic finders to search for null values, you need to use the `findBySomethingIsNull` version instead.  Try

```
def user = (session.email ? User.findByEmail(session.email)
                          : User.findByEmailIsNull())
```

Note that even if `User.findByEmail(null)` worked correctly every time, it would not necessarily give you the correct results on all databases as a `findBySomething(null)` would translate to

```
WHERE something = null
```

in the underlying SQL query, and according to the SQL spec `null` is not equal to anything else (not even to `null`).  You have to use `something is null` in SQL to match null values, which is what `findBySomethingIsNull()` translates to.

You could write a static utility method in the `User` class to gather this check into one place

```
public static User byOptEmail(val) {
  if(val == null) {
    return User.findByEmailIsNull()
  }
  User.findByEmail(val)
}
```

and then use `User.byOptEmail(session.email)` in your controllers.

Comment: I don't use the findBy to search for null values but may happen that the paramas passed to null by is null. In this case I expect a null result. But not an inpredictable result or a missing method exception. This is bad and force me to always check null values before calling findBy. I have always to do something like this?! `if(session.email){u = User.findByEmail(session.email)}`. I think not.

Comment: @FabianoTaioli I would put the check into a utility method in the `User` class (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Brown from grails nabble forum has identified my problem. It's a GORM bug. [see jira](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3463)

More info on this [thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Strange-finder-behavior-td4638643.html)

This [jira](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9628) too

Answer (score 0):

I tried with debugger and it looks it should be working, as you write. Maybe the groovy itself is a little bit confused here, try to help it this way:

```
User.findByEmail( session['email'] )
```

Comment: "a little bit confused" means a groovy bug in your opinion?

Comment: I remember something similar by me some time ago. you haven't written the Grails/Groovy version. It must not be necessary bug, just some dark corner of the groovy parser ;-) Did my advice help?

Comment: Paste your domain class and the controller code, please. This is very unusual!

Comment: My app is very huge... I try to reproduce the problem in a test app and I'll post it